# Git deleted my entire folder, even though I only deleted the contents of the folder

Tags: git, github

So I deleted the folder contents and then git wrote that my entire folder was deleted. I accidentally pushed this into production and now my entire folder in production also got deleted. Is there anyway to get my folder contents back? I tried rolling back to the previous commit and that didn't do it.

Comment: Rolling back will only restore stuff that was in version control before you removed the folder. It won't restore untracked files that may have been in production (user uploads, temporary files, etc.). In the future, to remove a folder's contents and keep the empty folder, put an empty `.gitignore` file in it.

Comment: git doesn't keeps track of empty folders. I think that's why git didn't keep track of folder with deleted contents. @ceejayoz should be .gitkeep file.

Comment: @Eyorther The exact filename doesn't really matter. I like `.gitignore` as it may be useful there in the future. Hell, `.keep-me-or-everything-will-explode` would be fine.

Comment: Awesome thanks guys!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository)